# tweepy api.me() not returning user objects of friends

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So from the tweepy documentation, I should be able to user api.me() to get a list of friends a user is following: http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/api.html#user-methods
First,I did usual OAuth dance:

```
import tweepy
consumer_token='#####'
consumer_secret='$$$$$'
access_token='&&&&&'
access_token_secret='****'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
daysinn_friends=api.me('DaysInnCanada')
```

And then python gave me an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
daysinn_friend=api.me('DaysInnCanada')
TypeError: me() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

But I didn't pass 2 arguments into me(), the only argument was the screen_name. I'm really confused and couldn't figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "extra" parameter that's confusing you is the Python `self` parameter. I've already written a long explanation of `self` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16259484/2314532, so instead of repeating it I'll just point you to that answer. If after reading that you still don't understand what's going on, let me know and I'll see if I can explain further.

Also, looking at the API documentation for tweepy, `me()` is supposed to take no parameters, and you're passing it one. From glancing at your code, I suspect what you really meant to do is call `api.followers("DaysInnCanada")`. Or maybe `api.get_user("DaysInnCanada")`, but I suspect you meant to use `followers`.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wants to get a list of his friends (i.e. people he is following), not people who follow him.

```
friends = api.friends_ids('DaysInnCanada')
obj = api.lookup_users(user_ids=friends)
for name in obj:
    print name.screen_name
```

For a list of all attributes associated with a `<tweepy.Models.User object>`, use `name.__getstate__()`

Comment: This causes `tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Too many terms specified in query.', 'code': 18}]`